# Color mapping for 16-bit greyscale values with smooth transitions

Tags: colormap, color-space, color-mapping

I have 16-bits of precision for my data. Trying to visualize this data in greyscale 8-bit leads to significant banding. My thought was that I could store these 16 bit values in colors. For example, the first 8 bits could be in the red channel, and the next 8 bits in the green channel.

However, this will lead to abrupt transitions. Going from 65280 (255,0,0) to 65279 (254,255,0) would cause the color to shift immediately from Red to Yellow. This is really not helpful to human interpretation.

I know that HSB could provide 360 degrees of variation pretty easily, but 360 color values isn't really that much more than the 256 I already have with 8-but greyscale.

What would be the most appropriate way to represent values between 0-65535 in terms of colors that transition in a way that make sense to humans?

Comment: Adding color to data usually adds an implied classification. This may force a certain interpretation. Have you tried dithering to smooth the banding?

Comment: 8 bits should not give you colour banding. So I would check your monitor (many monitors can display only 6 bits), and settings of your monitor (brightness/contrast). [our eyes "see 10bits" on greyscale, monitor are not so good on very bright and on blacks]. Possibly you may check your function to convert data into greyscale. Do you have full 16bit range? Could you use other functions, instead of just truncate the low 8 bits? On photography these are the "log" functions, to expand dynamic range (so input more then 8bit) without banding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you are counting the RGB values in a way that (255, 0, 0) follows (254, 255, 0). It seem like it should proceed in some variant of:

`(0, 0, 0) -> (254, 0, 0) -> (254, 1, 0) -> (254, 254, 0) -> (254, 254, 1) -> (254, 254, 254)`.

This would represent a transition from black to white through red, orange and yellow without any abrupt changes. Because of the non-linear way our eyes work it may not be perceived as perfectly smooth, but you should be able to do it without significant banding. For example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let rgb = [0, 0, 0]
// fill channels fromgre
for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
  for (let i = 0; i < 254; i++) {
    rgb[j]++
    ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${rgb.join(",")}, 1)`
    ctx.fillRect(i +254*j, 0, 1, 50);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="765"></canvas>
```

Or through blue by starting at the other end:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let rgb = [0, 0, 0]
// fill channels fromgre
for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
  for (let i = 0; i < 254; i++) {
    rgb[2-j]++
    ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${rgb.join(",")}, 1)`
    ctx.fillRect(i +254*j, 0, 1, 50);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="765"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Well, the reason I was storing them as I suggested was because I have potentially 65535 different values, and I was looking at it from the perspective of binary. In other words, I broke the 16-bit binary values down into two 8-bit binary values. (255, 255, 0) -> (1111 1111, 1111 1111, 0) -> 65535. This made it very straight forward in implementing programmatically.

Comment: I suppose I could do some sort of modulo operation to map the integer to the correct value in a 1x3 array of (255, 255, 255) possibilities.  

I guess I was looking at it as "How can I make use of as many colors as possible?"

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do it, if you want to keep one property: similar numbers should have similar colour, or better the inverse: very different numbers should never give similar colours.

But if you wrote about banding, it could seems that data are gradient like, so eyes could me more forgiven if two different "number zone" have similar colours, because of context of nearby colours.

I would not go to full 16 bits (which would be too much, and we cannot see all RGB colour distinctly, and few people have really good monitors). Possibly you may build an interface, which can zoom in, and add more contrast on restricted range.

For less bits, you can start with blue-green (0,x,x) going up [x from 0 to 255], then moving to green (0,255,x) [from 255 to 0], then to black (0, x, 0), from 255 to 0, then to yellow (x,x,0), then to red (255,0,0), then to black then to violet (x,0,x), then to blue, then to black, and finally to white (x,x,x).

So 10 scales, which give us just more then 3 additional bit of information.

I would probably never go to black (as you see, it is repeated), but just x until 5 or 10, which will reduce the number of bits. But so I think you still have 11 bit of information, and scale are distinguishable by human eyes.

In this example I used the 6 primaries+secondary colours (+greyscale), so they are easy distinguishable. In theory one could use additional intermediate colours, but I think it would confuse much more our eyes.

I would offer an additional input to shift up and down the original data numbers, so that user could check in more details (and getting more bits) some regions. But this work nicely if there are not many extreme changes between nearby numbers,